# HTTPS 500 error when using INSERT statements

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have been trying to make my new web app project thing live recently. I had all the code working on a local XAMPP server using a typical LAMP stack. But now that I'm making it live, I have noticed that when I have an INSERT statement in my PHP code, the server will always return a 500 error. But when I have a static page or just a SELECT statement, it works fine.

I have already given all the privileges and even logged in as root in my php/mysql connect statement but that didn't help.

```
<?php                                                                                
$conn= new mysqli ('localhost','username','password','ips');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);          
}                                                
$insert = "INSERT INTO ipaddr (ip) VALUES ($_POST['ip'])"; ?>


<form action="index.php" method="POST" style="visibility: visible;">                                    
<input type="password" name="ip" value=<?php echo($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])?>/>
```

this results in a 500 error, but a similar script with only a SELECT statement (like a gimmick online store thing) works fine.

EDIT: it was pointed out to me that I used the wrong variable name in the script, however this didn't fix it so the question still stands

Comment: Why are you saving the connection in `$mysqli` and then use `$conn` - Where did that come from?

Comment: Have you try removing the brackets from echo($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['ip'])) { $insert = "INSERT ...`

Comment: @AlonEitan woops, that was a sanity check that I copied and pasted from somewhere elese, but even if I fix it, it doesnt solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the initiated variable `$mysqli` in below instead of `$conn`,

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost','username','password','ips');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);          
}
```

I have formatted you code as below,

```
<?php                                                                                
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost','username','password','ips');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);          
}                                                

if(isset($_POST['ip'])) {
 $ip_address = $_POST['ip'];   
 $insert = "INSERT INTO ipaddr (ip) VALUES ('{$ip_address}')"; 
}

?>


<form action="index.php" method="POST" style="visibility: visible;">                                    
<input type="password" name="ip" value="<?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>"/>   
</form>
```

Comment: yes I just noticed that, however if I fix the variable name I still get the 500 error and I don't get an error message. Thanks though

Comment: And don't interpolate, bind.